# Ozonolysis of alkene

Tags: organic-chemistry, ozone, c-c-addition

[image]
(*from Wikipedia*)

I am having trouble in the last step where the alkene ozonide is reduced to ketones / aldehydes specifically in the presence of water. My teacher is telling me that water will be abstracting an oxygen atom to form $\ce{H2O2}$.

But why? Both oxygen atoms already have a complete octet, and further are repelled by their electron clouds. Why does water abstract an oxygen atom at all?

Comment: I was always under the impression that you needed a mild reducing agent, like dimethyl sulfide. I could see the same mechanism working with water, but am rather skeptical, because water is a pretty bad reducing agent, and on top of that if you put H2O2 in there you will get carboxylic acids (that's the "oxidative workup")...

Comment: Agree with orthocresol, a workup with just water makes no sense. It´s probably going to happen if you leave the trioxolane on the shelf with water for a week, and you get a wild mixture of ketones/aldehydes and acids. Not synthetically useful.

Comment: Not as far as I'm aware. You need to introduce a reducing agent, usually a sulfide, sometimes a phosphine. I think your teacher is in error.

Answer (score 2):

When the ozonide is reduced to Ketone/Aldehyde, We're concerned with what is called the "reductive workup" . We can summarize it like this:

[image: reductive ozonolysis]

If we look a little further into the mechanism (of a different alkene):
[image: mechanism]

Step (e) is what we're concerned with. Water is not having an impact on this reaction in any manner. The main compound here that's assisting this reaction is $\ce{(CH3)_2S}$  which is a mild reducing agent.

---

**Source of the pictures**:
[Reaction summary](https://www.masterorganicchemistry.com/2013/04/23/alkene-reactions-ozonolysis/)
[Reaction mechanism](https://www.ch.imperial.ac.uk/rzepa/blog/?p=6708)

Comment: I agree. If you work up an ozonolysis reaction mixture with just water, you get the ozonide. DO NOT DO THIS - ozonides are explosive.

Comment: I'll keep that in mind when I enter the lab (I won't be doing so in the near future :P )