Mechanism for reductive and oxidative "ozonide" workup
So, I've been studying the process of "ozonolysis" and upon reviewing it's mechanism have satisfactorily understood till the formation of "ozonide". I have reviewed several resources and have not found a satisfactory resource depicting the mechanism for the "oxidative/reductive workup" of the formed ozonide.
Can anyone help in providing the mechanism (or any resource) for the oxidative workup of ozonide (using H₂O₂) and the reductive workup of ozonide (using Zn and Water)? Additionally, it would be very helpful if someone could explain the reasoning for using Zn, Water and H₂O₂ respectively.

Note: I found conflicting steps for these mechanisms at different sources. For eg: In the case of "reductive workup" (using Zn + Water or sometimes just water);

Several videos online depict a step of the attachment of hydroxyl (-OH) groups to oxide alongside bond breaking to form an unstable intermediate which forms the respective aldehyde/ketone by loss of water.
Although, some sources directly depict the formation of the carbonyl double bond alongside bond breaking with the omission of the unstable hydroxyl attached intermediate step.


Plenty on ozonolysis on ChemSE. Type "ozonolysis" in the Search Bar at the top of the page. Also here.

Sir I did find stuff on ozonolysis on ChemSE although none of them seem to clear the doubt I had as either they are unanswered or answer something else. As I mentioned in the "note" section, there are conflicting steps for reductive workup in the sources I did see. Similarly, the above mentioned link does not show oxidative workup.

I apologize if I still missed something though, it may have been an oversight on my part.

What makes you think these mechanisms are well known? Even mechanisms of preceding steps aren't really important... Well, this whole reaction isn't important from practical point of view. Would you like to use O3 gas as oxidiser? I don't think so. You should just be able to tell what products of such reactions are or alternatively what substrates if products are known.

You may want to review search results from site:stackexchange.com OR site:libretexts.org OR site:wikipedia.org ozonolysis

Yes sir I reviewed these sources, and upon reading from some sources I have posted a conflicting mechanism I found online as compared to the mechanism provided by @user55119

https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/62145/reaction-mechanism-for-ozonolysis

Also see: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/a/138487/17368

FWIW, the mechanism is called "Crigee mechanism".

If I understand you correctly, you want to known the mechanism for the reduction with zinc and oxidation with hydrogen peroxide of an ozonide. A rational mechanism may be drawn to account for the observed products. To understand them, it is imperative to appreciate the oxidation states involved. In Scheme 1 the ozonide is derived from a typical, symmetrical linear alkene. If one were to conduct a "hypothetical hydrolysis" of the ozonide, the products would be an aldehyde and a carboxylic acid that are not the products of a "normal" ozonolysis. The transformation of any carboxylic acid to an aldehyde requires a 2-electron reduction [red arrow], which is precisely the role of zinc [$\ce{Zn^o \rightarrow ZnO}$] or dimethyl sulfide [$\ce{Me2S \rightarrow Me2SO}$]. Likewise, if one desired two carboxylic acids, some 2-electron oxidant would be required for the aldehyde [red arrow]. That is the role of hydrogen peroxide in your question.

The oxidation in Scheme 2 is stoichiometric in hydrogen peroxide and is performed in aqueous base. Attack of hydroxide --- or for that matter the anion of hydrogen peroxide [1] --- on the weak O-O bond forms an aldehyde and intermediate 1, which collapses via 1,2-hydride transfer to a carboxylic acid and hydroxide followed by neutralization. Water is the reduction product of hydrogen peroxide. Intermediate 1 may also be formed by the addition of the anion of hydrogen peroxide to the aldehyde.


1) The hydroperoxy anion would return itself in the fragmentation of the anion.

Ah! So, to summarise for the both the reductive and oxidative workups, the role of water is to perform hydrolysis on the ozonide and then either Zn or H2O2 is used for the oxidation/reduction. Is this correct? (As for scheme 2, do you mean that oxidative workup can also be done through a base + H2O2 albeit through a different mechanism?)

Thank you for taking time out and answering my question!

Oxidative workup mechanism Sir, herein the mechanism listed from "step 5" onwards is different as compared to the "scheme 2" mechanism provided by you. It suggests breakage of O-O bond by decomposition while you suggest that it is initiated by the base (or peroxide). Which one of these is correct then?

Under neutral conditions solvolysis of the ozonide may apply. The mechanism in your link is reasonable.

Sir I am sorry to disturb you again but there is something that I am not able to grasp satisfactorily. Reductive | Oxidative. Now in these mechanisms, why is it that we consider the decomposing of ozonide in one case and not in the other case?

Similarly, in the "reductive mechanism" I linked there is no formation of RCO₂H first which should've been there according to your "scheme 1". Also, there is attack on both the products in the case of "oxidative" but only on one product in the case of "reductive", is there any reason for it? I just wish to understand the logic behind the mechanism or is it one of those things that I'll just have to take it the way it is?

I have posted reasonable mechanism for formation of Staudinger ozonide and follow-up of reductive workup elsewhere. I found a reliable arrow-pushing mechanism for the oxidative workup in Master Organic Chemistry and here is the oxidative workup of the ozonide:


I think upon some research I have understood some stuff regarding the mechanism and would like to add on some stuff for summarization (although I can be completely wrong as well) †.
Firstly, the mechanism ozonide formation is most correctly presented by the "Criegee Mechanism" (a three-step process that goes from I.O to Intermediate products to F.O). After the formation of the unstable I.O (initial ozonide), there takes place the formation of a "carbonyl compound" + "zwitterion intermediate" (a carbonyl oxide).
Secondly, there are two paths these products can take; either they can join together to form the F.O (final ozonide) or they can remain as they are and get intercepted by the reagent present. (although, this depends on the reaction conditions and the type of reagent) (1)

In case of oxidative workup, as showed in the answer above, there is formation of the F.O first which is attacked by OH- and peroxide step-wise. (I'm researching on a step-wise mechanism for this as well the use of OH- as a reagent since  H+ would make more sense for easier protonation of the O-O bond of the F.O)

Similarly, in case of reductive workup, if we use Me₂S (dimethyl sulphide) then there is formation of the F.O first which is then attacked by the Me₂S. Although, if we use Me₂S in the presence of MeOH (methanol) then the carbonyl oxide is intercepted by the methanol to give ("hydroperoxy acetal" followed by reduction with Me₂S) and the reaction proceeds without the formation of the F.O first.


Hence, I the difference in mechanisms for the same type of work-up is due to the fact that different reagents used cause attacks on different areas; "O-O bond attack" in the case of F.O formation but "direct attack on the products" in case of intermediate products interception (no F.O formation).

Note: This explanation is based on some papers I have reviewed online as well as some answers here on ChemSE. I am yet to find a specific "correct" mechanism per say.
 † This answer could very well be completely wrong as I am no expert and just a high-school student studying OChem. This is just something I researched about. If there is any misinformation in this answer, I'll gladly delete it.  Thanks!
 (1) Review page no. 17-25 for Criegee mechanism and F.O formation/intermediate interception.
